# Any way to tell DNS resolver in go to lookup IPV4 address only?

Tags: go

I'm trying to configure a Go program (namely, Prometheus) to only look up IPv4 addresses, but seems the `LookupIP` function that the program uses for DNS resolution doesn't have an option for that.

Is there any way I can work around it, or am I getting something wrong?
the `LookupIP` function as in the [src](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/lookup.go):

```golang
// LookupIP looks up a host using the local resolver.
// It returns a slice of that host's IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
func LookupIP(host string) ([]IP, error) {
    addrs, err := DefaultResolver.LookupIPAddr(context.Background(), host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ips := make([]IP, len(addrs))
    for i, ia := range addrs {
        ips[i] = ia.IP
    }
    return ips, nil
}
```

Comment: there is no IPv6 deployment yet in our environment. so any IPv6 lookups will just return NXDOMAIN. the program can get IPv4 addresses correctly, but I just don't want it to send IPv6 queries. @DanielFarrell

Comment: Try this 
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-dns/blob/main/internal/provider/lookup.go

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for LookupIP. It's the same function but your pass the ip network you are targeting.

```
// LookupIP looks up host for the given network using the local resolver.
// It returns a slice of that host's IP addresses of the type specified by
// network.
// network must be one of "ip", "ip4" or "ip6".
func (r *Resolver) LookupIP(ctx context.Context, network, host string) ([]IP, error) {
```

Usage:

```
    net.DefaultResolver.LookupIP(context.Background(), "ip4", "host")
```

Comment: yeah, I saw that function in the same source file I mentioned in my question, but don't know how to call it.

The function is called in Prometheus's source file like the following, but don't know how to make sure it calls this function instead of the one with the same name but no option to specify network type.

```go
        ips, err := net.LookupIP(hostname)
        if err != nil {
                // Return the system hostname if we can't look up the IP address.
                return hostname, nil 
        }

```

Comment: Updating my questions with usage.

Comment: great! I'll try to re-compile that program with this function and see how things work. Thanks!